# What is the reference made in this quote from the final boss?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

After beating the final boss, you remove chips in the Mammal Pod.

During that time, the Mamal Pod quote

> The Boss

But one of the quote I don't remember from the original character is:

> Shall we walk through the rainy plain of Spain?

Does anyone know what this quote mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote is a reference to a song from "My Fair Lady (1956)". The name of the song is "The Rain in Spain"; it has music by Frederick Loewe and lyrics by Alan Jay Lerner.

The phrase being referenced is "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain."  The significance of it was that the lead female character was unable to say the sentence because of her strong Cockney accent.  Her ability to speak without the accent was a major turning point in the movie and signified her cultural indoctrination into British aristocracy.  The movie, itself, is an adaptation of the George Bernard Shaw play "Pygmalion".